# How to only invoke a function that's called from within another function when a specific div is NOT clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am calling `campusInfo(id)` a few places in my code. 
Inside `campusInfo(id)` function I am calling `campusInfo_2(HouseID)`.

One of the instances where I am calling `campusInfo(id)` is on the onclick of a div. 
In this case I don't want campusInfo_2(HouseID) invoked.

Here is the campusInfo(id) javascript function which calls campusInfo_2(HouseID)

```
//campus information
function campusInfo(id) {
    fetch(`https://api/` + id)
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(r => {
            const mapClassToResponse = {
                '.campus-name': 'name',
               '.program-levels-values:eq(4)': 'annualTuition'
            };
            var HouseID = r['Houses'][0]['HouseID'];

        Object.keys(mapClassToResponse).map(k => {

            $(k).html(r[mapClassToResponse[k]]);
        });

        //formatting numbers to have commas
        $(".program-levels-values:eq(4)").digits();
        $(".campus-number:eq(0)").digits();
        $(".campus-number:eq(1)").digits();            

        //program-levels
        $(r.programLevels).each(function (index, item) {
            $('.program-levels-values:eq(0)').append(item.programLevel + ' ');
        });

        //institution control
        if (r.isInstitutionControlPublic == false) {
            $('.program-levels-values:eq(2)').html('Private');
        } else {
            $('.program-levels-values:eq(2)').html('Public');
        }

campusInfo_2(HouseID);            
    }).catch(console.log);
 };
```

Here is the div where I don't want campusInfo_2(HouseID) being invoked

```
  <div class="other-school" onclick="campusInfo(10)"><label 
  class="other-schools-list">Portland State University</label</div>
```

Here is what I tried thus far but it was saying in console that the element was undefined.

```
  if(document.getElementsByClassName('other-school').clicked == false)
        {
        campusInfo_2(HouseID);
        }
```

Comment: You could pass in a second argument of `false` to the method.  If that argument `=== false`, don't do the campusInfo_2 call.

Comment: @taplar Would it be possible for you to update the code to reflect your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggested solution would be to provide an additional argument.

```
<div class="other-school" onclick="campusInfo(10, false)">
```

Then your method definition would change to:

```
function campusInfo(id, skipSecondCampusInfo) {
```

If you only pass that in on the inline binding, then it will be `undefined` on all the other calls.  So then your call could be surrounded with:

```
if (skipSecondCampusInfo !== false) campusInfo_2(HouseID);
```

In which case if it is undefined, it will execute it.  Otherwise, if it is false, it will not.

Comment: thank you so much! worked as needed! Is there a way when I call campusInfo() on the click of the div to wipe out the previous data or do i need to set each element to empty string? Because when its reloading now with new data some of the old data is persisting. Because the new id doesn't have values for some of the elements taht the previous id had values for. So instead of displaying an empty string its persisting the old value

Comment: @user11351969 Reading back over this, I might suggest you change it to `campusInfo(10, true)` and check for `!== true`.  Since we **are** telling it when to skip the method call, passing in `false` is kinda weird, ^_^

Comment: You might want to post an additonal question for your comment, as that seems to go beyond the "skip the method call" subject this one was about, :)

Comment: Ok thank you. I just have to wait 90 minutes between posting questions. Do you know why this question was voted down twice?

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me right now as to why it was.